# push specific files using egit

Tags: eclipse, macos, git, egit

I thought this would be a no pbrainer, but for some reason can't find anything on the issue - is there a way to push only specific files from egit? Our repository contains a lrage number of files which are mainly of no interest to me, and every time I try to push I get many DIRTY_TREE errors in files I don't care about. Right-clicking on a file and then attempting push, just tryes to push the entire repository
I'm using Eclipse Juno from mac, and BitBucket repository
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git push deals with commit objects, not with files. If you want to push specific files, you have to make a commit that contains only those files. In your case, you might want to look at the `git update-index --assume-unchanged <files>` command, or at the `.git/info/exclude` file, which is like `.gitignore` except it's for your local repository only (doesn't get shared with the upstream repo).

Comment: Thanks! I see that your commands are in command line form, do you know how this is done with egit? Apparently using git cli from mac requires additional software, which I'd prefer not to download if it isn't necessary

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unfamiliar with egit. The `.git/info/exclude` is just a file that you can edit with any text editor.

Comment: well, I got sick of egit so I dl'ed regular command line git, and worked from there. I'll accept your answer as it's the only one her. Thanks! :)